# closures in for loops in javascript

Tags: javascript, closures

I am trying to reproduce the example with the IIEF here:

[Understand JavaScript Closures With Ease](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-closures-with-ease/)

**EDIT**

It's under *3. Closures Gone Awry*

This is my code:

```js
var myArray = ["a", "b", "c"];

function doSomething(someArray) {
  var counter = 10;
  for (var i = 0; i < someArray.length; i++) {
    someArray[i] = function(inner_i) {
      return function() {
        return counter += inner_i;
      }();
    }(i);
  }
  return someArray;
}

var newArray = doSomething(myArray);
console.log(newArray[0]);
console.log(newArray[1]);
console.log(newArray[2]);
```

The output is

```
10
11
13
```

instead of

```
10
11
12
```

What am I doing differently?

Comment: The inner_i is 2 in your third loop which means: `counter+=inner_i` equals `11+2=13` just `return counter + inner_i`

Comment: `return counter + inner_i;`

Comment: *"What am I doing differently?"* How are we to know? You haven't shown the code you're comparing your code to.

Comment: Thanks guys! Not seeing the forest for the trees!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: It's in the link I provided.

Comment: @NotSmartButLucky: Questions **must** be self-contained; external links rot. When they do, the question and its answers are no longer of value to others in the future. That's why SO requires self-contained questions. (And answers.)

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong in the result, because you are updating the value of `counter` in each iteration. Instead just return the sum of `counter` and `i`.

```js
var myArray = ["a", "b", "c"];

function doSomething(someArray) {
  var counter = 10;
  for (var i = 0; i < someArray.length; i++) {

    someArray[i] = function(inner_i) {
      return function() {
        return counter + inner_i;
      }();
    }(i);
  }

  return someArray;
}

var newArray = doSomething(myArray);
console.log(newArray[0]);
console.log(newArray[1]);
console.log(newArray[2]);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Totally didn't see that!